# @Scheduled Expression with cron expression sometimes executes the task twice

Tags: micronaut

Scheduled task gets executed twice when using the cron expression with @Scheduled annotation.

I am using @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7-23 ? * 1-5") to execute a task on the hour from morning 7 till 23 pm. However, sometimes task gets executed twice

```
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T16:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T17:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T18:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T18:59:58  (This shouldn't have executed)
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T19:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T19:59:59   (Neither should this)
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T20:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T21:00:00
>Running Task::LocalTime 2019-08-30T22:00:00
```

Am I doing something wrong ? When tried same expression with Spring/SpringBoot it seems to run correctly.

Edit : Code

```java
    package imbibing.oldman
        @Singleton
        public class NotifyHourlyToDrink {
            private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotifyHourlyToDrink.class);
            private int numberOfBeersDrank;

            @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7-23 ? * 1-5")
            public void drinkBeer(){
                    numberOfBeersDrank++;
                    LOGGER.info("Oh! The chilled  number {}", numberOfBeersDrank);  
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you provide the code of your sheduled class?

Comment: Added code in the edit above. Too difficult to add it in comments

Comment: Check you cron job pattern

Comment: You perhaps talking about the typo (the extra parenthesis). Edited it. I made the example up and perhaps overlooked, however the point being -  I am not doing anything spectacular in  my code. And sometimes the job runs twice as can be seen in the logs

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug and fixed in Micronaut 1.2.1

Comment: I tried it with 1.2.1 and it works. Thank you. I tried to upvote the answer but I am still not allowed.